# changing opacity on hover doesn't work

Tags: css

I'd like to change the opacity of the cross (.cross) when hovering over it to 0.9.
Changing the opacity to 0.3 when hovering over a div surrounding the image works, but not the change to 0.9

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12598822/midori.html

```
.cross {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: url(close.svg);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.shortcut .preview:hover > #crosshidden {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 150ms;
    opacity: 0.3;
    display: block;
}

.cross:hover > #crosshidden {
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.cross:hover > #crosshidden` isn't working because the `<a>` has both the class of `cross` and the ID of `crosshidden` but doesn't have any children as implied by your child combinator `>`

Comment: .cross:hover { should be enough, right?

When I add a style attribute that is obvious like width: 120px; I can see that hover works, since the background image is visible several times. but the opacity still doesn't change.

Comment: Yes `cross:hover` should be enough .. by any chance can you put your relevant code in a simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HWCvE/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Google Chrome Developer Tools I noticed that your **"div.shortcut .preview:hover > #crosshidden"** CSS block has higher precedence over **".cross:hover > #crosshidden"**.

A suitable solution was to replace the later block for:

```
div.shortcut .preview:hover > #crosshidden:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```